# Multiple acme sections for multiple customers with single traefik ingress controller in kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, lets-encrypt, traefik, kubernetes-ingress

Situation:

I want many customers share a common set of public IPs to access the kubernetes cluster.

Hostname based routing within the cluster it's done. But I want to provide HTTPS for all my customer's domains.

I have a set of edge-router nodes with one public IP each one. There's a Traefik ingress controller configured as DaemonSet listening on these nodes.

Let's supose there can be thousands customers with thousands domains.

My problem is that I want to have mulitple `acme` sections.

Exctracted from a ConfigMap in my ingress controller manifest:

```
[acme]
  email = "ca@mycompany.com"
  storage = "/etc/traefik/acme.json"
  entryPoint = "https"    
  onHostRule = true
  caServer = "https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory"
[[acme.domains]]
  main = "mycustomer1.com"
[acme.httpChallenge]
  entryPoint = "http"
```

My ideal solution would be have a way to split each customer https configuration in separate files, each one with its own acme settings.

Or, even better, having a way of configure this from the ingress resource:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
name: ingress
namespace: garden
annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: traefik

    #
    # LET'S ENCRYPT CONFIGURATION COULD BE HERE.
    # THAT WAY IT WOULD BE EASY TO CONFIGURE HTTPS FOR EACH CUSTOMER.
    #

spec:
rules:
    - host: mycustomer1.com
    http:
        paths:
        - path: /
            backend:
            serviceName: backend
            servicePort: 80
```

Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest trying to create multiple `kind: Ingress`  for each customer and manage them.  You will have the possibility to use special configmap for each Ingress class